# how to get more information on an exception

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I created a solution in visual studio 2008 on windows 7, 64 bit.

It works.

When I move it onto another machine, also win 7, 64 bit, it crashed with almost no information.

The original issue was this:

[call was rejected by callee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358944/call-was-rejected-by-callee)

I then implemented this solution:

[how to properly GetTypeFromProgID for visual studio 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12962467/how-to-properly-gettypefromprogid-for-visual-studio-2008)

However, now my issue is that when I run the executable on a different machine, the program is crashing immediately with the following information:

```
Description:
  Stopped working

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: EmailSalesVolumeSolution.exe
  Application Version:  1.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    508064dd
  Fault Module Name:    KERNELBASE.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7601.17932
  Fault Module Timestamp:   503285c2
  Exception Code:   e0434f4d
  Exception Offset: 000000000000caed
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

I wrapped the code in a `try/catch`, and still did not get a proper error message:

```
static void Main()
{
    try
    {
        EnvDTE80.DTE2 dte;
        object obj = null;
        System.Type t = null;

        // Get the ProgID for DTE 8.0.
        t = System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID("VisualStudio.DTE.9.0",
          true);
        // Create a new instance of the IDE.
        obj = System.Activator.CreateInstance(t, true);
        // Cast the instance to DTE2 and assign to variable dte.
        dte = (EnvDTE80.DTE2)obj;

        // Register the IOleMessageFilter to handle any threading
        // errors.
        MessageFilter.Register();
        // Display the Visual Studio IDE.
        dte.MainWindow.Activate();


        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        Application.Run(new Form1());

        // For example, get a reference to the solution2 object
        // and do what you like with it.

        // All done, so shut down the IDE...
        dte.Quit();
        // and turn off the IOleMessageFilter.
        MessageFilter.Revoke();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

**How can I identify where exactly the exception occurred and WHAT IS the exception?**

I do have some unmanaged code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using EnvDTE;
using EnvDTE80;
using EnvDTE90;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace EmailSalesVolumeSolution
{
    public class MessageFilter : IOleMessageFilter
    {
        //
        // Class containing the IOleMessageFilter
        // thread error-handling functions.

        // Start the filter.
        public static void Register()
        {
            IOleMessageFilter newFilter = new MessageFilter();
            IOleMessageFilter oldFilter = null;
            CoRegisterMessageFilter(newFilter, out oldFilter);
        }

        // Done with the filter, close it.
        public static void Revoke()
        {
            IOleMessageFilter oldFilter = null;
            CoRegisterMessageFilter(null, out oldFilter);
        }

        //
        // IOleMessageFilter functions.
        // Handle incoming thread requests.
        int IOleMessageFilter.HandleInComingCall(int dwCallType,
          System.IntPtr hTaskCaller, int dwTickCount, System.IntPtr
          lpInterfaceInfo)
        {
            //Return the flag SERVERCALL_ISHANDLED.
            return 0;
        }

        // Thread call was rejected, so try again.
        int IOleMessageFilter.RetryRejectedCall(System.IntPtr
          hTaskCallee, int dwTickCount, int dwRejectType)
        {
            if (dwRejectType == 2)
            // flag = SERVERCALL_RETRYLATER.
            {
                // Retry the thread call immediately if return >=0 & 
                // <100.
                return 99;
            }
            // Too busy; cancel call.
            return -1;
        }

        int IOleMessageFilter.MessagePending(System.IntPtr hTaskCallee,
          int dwTickCount, int dwPendingType)
        {
            //Return the flag PENDINGMSG_WAITDEFPROCESS.
            return 2;
        }

        // Implement the IOleMessageFilter interface.
        [DllImport("Ole32.dll")]
        private static extern int
          CoRegisterMessageFilter(IOleMessageFilter newFilter, out 
          IOleMessageFilter oldFilter);
    }
    [ComImport(), Guid("00000016-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"),
    InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    interface IOleMessageFilter
    {
        [PreserveSig]
        int HandleInComingCall(
            int dwCallType,
            IntPtr hTaskCaller,
            int dwTickCount,
            IntPtr lpInterfaceInfo);

        [PreserveSig]
        int RetryRejectedCall(
            IntPtr hTaskCallee,
            int dwTickCount,
            int dwRejectType);

        [PreserveSig]
        int MessagePending(
            IntPtr hTaskCallee,
            int dwTickCount,
            int dwPendingType);
    }
}
```

after installing VS 2008 express on the machine that gave me trouble, i am now getting this:

[image]

Comment: Can you point on specific line after you attached a debugger ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution that worked was installing Visual studio. As soon as it was installed, I got the exact exception.

Comment: Just as a FYI, a APPCRASH with a fault module of KERNELBASE.dll means a exception was thrown while you where inside KERNELBASE.dll. In C# this usually means one of your Interop calls has somthing wrong with it. Personally I have had this happen to me due to a typo in a method signature, from the screenshot of the error once you got visual studio it looks like maybe a invalid GUID for your com object (maybe it is not registered)

Comment: @thank you SO much for your advice! woudl this be true even though this works on my machine and not on another machine?

Comment: Your DLL may not be registered on the client machine. Check the DLL that you are calling the COM object for and do a `Regsvr32 YouComDllName.dll` as administrator. Depending on if you are using a 32 bit or 64 bit application you may need to either use the copy of Regsvr32 in `C:\Windows\System32` or in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` (In a backwards way the 64 bit version is in system32 and the 32 bit version is in SysWOW64)

Comment: @Danpe what is  exact  solution please give me.

Answer (score 2):

Try printing more from the Exception:

```
catch(Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message + ":\n" + e.StackTrace);
}
```

You can use this to catch all Inner Excpetions as well:

```
string except = "Uncaught Exception: ";
while(e != null)
{
    except += e.Message + ";\n";
    e = e.InnerException;
}
```

---

If program crashes with no exception then you need to try and attach a Debugger,

You'll need **Visual Studio** installed on the machine or to be able to use Remote Desktop for remote debugging. [How to: Attach to a Running Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6wf8e4z.aspx)

### To attach to a running process:

1. On the Debug menu, select Attach to Process.
2. In the Attach to Process dialog box, find the program that you want
   to attach to from the Available Processes list.

   If the program that you want to debug is running on another
   computer, use the Qualifier list box to select the remote computer.
   For more information, see How to: Select a Remote Machine.

   If the process is running under a different user account, select the
   Show processes from all users check box.

   If you are connected through Remote Desktop Connection, select the
   Show processes in all sessions check box.
3. In the Attach to box, make sure that the type of code you will debug
   is listed. The default Automatic setting tries to determine what
   type of code you want to debug. If the automatic setting is not
   appropriate:
4. Click Select.
5. In the Select Code Type dialog box, click Debug these code types and
   select the types to debug.
6. Click OK.
7. Click Attach.

### **You MUST compile the executable with DEBUG mode**

---

### UPDATE

I see you use `Type.GetTypeFromProgID` that requires **.NET 4.5**, Please make sure you have **.NET 4.5** installed on the PC that is throwing the error !

It seems that `t = System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID("VisualStudio.DTE.9.0", true);` is throwing [COMException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comexception.aspx) that means that "**VisualStudio.DTE.9.0**" is not registered in the other PC.

You should add **Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 DTE** as a dependency for your program.

Comment: Try attaching a debugger to see which line crashes

Comment: the program runs fine in debug and release mode on my machine, but when i move it to another machine, the executable spits out the above garbage

Comment: FWIW, e.ToString() gives the full exception message and stacktrace

Comment: Updated, let me know if you succeeds in attaching the debugger.

Comment: thank you very much what i am doing right now is downloading VS 2008 express

Comment: after it's downloaded iw ill try to compile with it on the other computer and let you know

Comment: Please try my latest solution. and Can you point on specific line after you attached a debugger ?

Comment: how would i add vs 9 dte as a dependency?

Comment: I dont know how you are installing your application but consider using [InstallSheild](http://www.installshield.com/) or reading this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011088/how-to-include-dependencies-in-setup-and-deployment-project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011088/how-to-include-dependencies-in-setup-and-deployment-project)

Answer (score 2):

You can try also to subscribe on `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` event:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += 
      (sender, e) => MessageBox.Show(e.ExceptionObject.ToString());
```

Do this at the top of `Main` method.

Comment: thank you, i just tried this, and still getting the same result

Comment: If you have visual studio on another machine, than you can add `Debugger.Break` command to walk through code in debugger. Btw do you have some unmanaged code invocations in your app?

Comment: thank you. i think i do have unmanaged code (i dont know what that is, but i pasted it)

Comment: try to add after your try ... catch block one more catch without parameter `catch { MessageBox.Show("Non-CLS compliant exception caught."); }`. At least we will know that we have non-CLS exception

Answer (score 1):

Your DLL may not be registered on the client machine. Check the DLL that you are calling the COM object for and do a `Regsvr32 YouComDllName.dll` in a administrative command prompt (right click on the command prompt icon and do `Run as Administrator`. Depending on if you are using a 32 bit or 64 bit application you may need to either use the copy of Regsvr32 in `C:\Windows\System32` or in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` (In a backwards way the 64 bit version is in system32 and the 32 bit version is in SysWOW64)

---

If just regestering the DLL on your machine does not work run [Dependancy Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) on the program on your computer. When you get all of the DLLs that your program touches, check the client computer is not missing any. The DLL you are calling may be there, but a DLL ***it depends on*** may not be.

Comment: Dependancy Walker can show you which dll is missing, just compare the list it gives you on your machine to the list you have on the other machine. Make sure you do `Profile->Start Profileing` when you run the dependancy walker as it won't pick up late bound DLL's like your COM DLL until you run it in the profiler.

Comment: scott, im still waiting for the user to log off the machine so that i can play with it, but would u suspect that this is the issue given that it is not working on two computers that do not have full version of visual studio installed yet it works on mine that DOES have full version of VS installed?

Comment: I find that unlikely. It is much more likely that there is a 3rd party DLL that has nothing to do with VS your code is relying on that was installed on your machine but is not installed on the client's machine. (If the DLL your program relies on was written(or at least complied once) in VS on your machine too I know it auto-regesters the DLL for testing if you have some settings set. that could be how it got registered). Or maybe it was a checkbox on a installer .msi you had checked that your client did not (example: the SQL SDK comes with SQL Server but is a optional install)

Comment: thank you again scott for so much help on this. there was no installer, i just copied the entire DEBUG folder on a different machine